# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException for a string variable

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, jfreechart

I am getting the error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public class NetworkAnalyzerWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {

String host = hostName.getText();



/**
 * Creates new form NetworkAnalyzerwindow
 * @param title
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
 */


public NetworkAnalyzerWindow(final String title) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    super(title);
    XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    chartPanel.setSize(pingPanel.getSize());
    pingPanel.add(chartPanel);
    pingPanel.getParent().validate();
    setContentPane(chartPanel);

}
//create dataset
private XYDataset createDataset() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{

    XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("series");
        for(int i = 0; i <10; i++){
           int ping = PingGraphData.getPing(host);
           series1.add(i, ping);
           Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    dataset.addSeries(series1);
    return dataset;   
}

//create chart
private JFreeChart createChart(XYDataset dataset){
    JFreeChart pingChart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Your Ping", //title
            "Time",      //x axis
            "Ping",      //y axis
            dataset,     //data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
            false,       //include legend
            false,       //tooltips
            false        //urls
    );
    final XYPlot plot = pingChart.getXYPlot();
    ValueAxis axis = plot.getDomainAxis();
    axis.setAutoRange(true);
    axis.setFixedAutoRange(60000.0);
    axis = plot.getRangeAxis();
    axis.setAutoRange(true);
    return pingChart;



}
/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    hostName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    startButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    maxPing = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    minPing = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    avgPing = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    pingPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);
    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);

    hostName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
    hostName.setText("Enter domain");
    hostName.setToolTipText("");

    startButton.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
    startButton.setText("Start");
    startButton.setToolTipText("Click here to test ping");
    startButton.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            startButtonMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    maxPing.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    maxPing.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    maxPing.setText("Max: ms");
    maxPing.setToolTipText("Ping");

    minPing.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    minPing.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    minPing.setText("Min: ms");

    avgPing.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
    avgPing.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    avgPing.setText("Avg: ms");

    pingPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout pingPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(pingPanel);
    pingPanel.setLayout(pingPanelLayout);
    pingPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        pingPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 504, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    pingPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        pingPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 346, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(23, 23, 23)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(hostName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 199, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(maxPing, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(minPing, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(avgPing, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(startButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 101, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(pingPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(51, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(hostName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(startButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(maxPing, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(minPing, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(avgPing, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 128, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addComponent(pingPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    hostName.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("");

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


private void startButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:



    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){

            try { 
                NetworkAnalyzer.pingCheck(host);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NetworkAnalyzerWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

            }
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);




}                                        


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetworkAnalyzerWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetworkAnalyzerWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetworkAnalyzerWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NetworkAnalyzerWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
    //</editor-fold>


    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new NetworkAnalyzerWindow("").setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NetworkAnalyzerWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(NetworkAnalyzerWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
public static javax.swing.JLabel avgPing;
public static javax.swing.JTextField hostName;
public static javax.swing.JLabel maxPing;
public static javax.swing.JLabel minPing;
public static javax.swing.JPanel pingPanel;
private javax.swing.JButton startButton;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
`
```

From the error messages, it seems like the errors are coming from these two lines:

```
   String host = hostName.getText();
```

and

```
new NetworkAnalyzerWindow("").setVisible(true);
```

I tried to google around, but I dont understand what I am doing wrong at all. Probably because I am still a noob, but if someone could help point me in the right direction, that would be nice

Comment: When you intiialise `host`; `String host = hostName.getText();`, the `JTextField` is not intiialised yet (meaning it's `null`)

Comment: FYI- Fields are initialised before the constructor of the class is called